# Runtime error on UVa judge

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am receiving a runtime error on UVa judge on problem 10189. I have tried really hard but I have been unable to find the cause of error.
In this problem we are supposed to find the hint matrix for a minesweeper field.Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char ch;
    int row, col, i, j, ans[101][101];
    int tot = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

    while (row != 0) {
        tot++;

        for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
            scanf("\n");
            for (j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
                ch = getchar();
                if (ch == '*') {
                    ans[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    ans[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }        
        for (i = 0; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            ans[i][0] = 0;
            ans[i][col+1] = 0;
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= col + 1; j++) {
            ans[0][j] = 0;
            ans[row+1][j] = 0;
        }

        printf("Field #%d\n", tot);
        for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
                if (ans[i][j] == 1)
                    printf("*");
                else {
                    printf("%d", ans[i-1][j-1] + ans[i-1][j] + ans[i-1][j+1] +
                                 ans[i][j-1]   +               ans[i][j+1] +
                                 ans[i+1][j-1] + ans[i+1][j] + ans[i+1][j+1]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        scanf("\n%d %d", &row, &col);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, I am sorry. I clicked on the post button by mistake.

Comment: You are getting out of the array bounds somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mine field may be `100x100`, you should make the array one column larger and one row longer: `ans[102][102]`.

Note that you could simplify the code by initializing this array to 0 before reading the minefield:

```
memset(ans, 0, sizeof ans);
```

You should definitely also check the return value of `scanf` to detect invalid input and/or premature EOF and avoid undefined behavior and endless loops.